# Jquery Timeago plugin to work with unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to make timeago plugin work with the following timestamps

> 2017-03-16 18:37:20

then i tried converting it to this timestamp.but its still not working

> 1489685840

Here is the code

```
  <script src="jquery.timeago.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="jquery.livequery.min" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".demo_class").timeago();
});
</script>
```

And since i am trying to do this in a table .here is the responsible code

```
<td>
                    <?php 
  $datetime = $row['date'];
  $datetime = strtotime($datetime);
?>
You opened this page <span  class='demo_class' ><?php echo $datetime ; ?></span>
</td>
```

If possible can u help me make the code autoupdating? like the time will change automatically without refreshing

Timeago uses something like this

> 2008-07-17T09:24:17Z

Comment: how about you tell us what format timeago expects? we are not going to go read its documentation for you

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: you can format the date with php `date()` or mysql `DATE_FORMAT()`

Answer (score 0):

Author of jquery-timeago here.

[As the docs reference](http://timeago.yarp.com/), an [ISO 8601](http://timeago.yarp.com/) timestamp is required for everything to work as expected in timeago:

```
<time class="timeago" datetime="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</time>
```

In PHP, you'll need a snippet like this to output ISO 8601 format:

```
$time->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```